# How to clear the beginning "ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement", and execute a dump file on Vagrant?

Tags: php, mysql, git, vagrant

I am a beginner of web-programming with Vagrant (my PC spec: windows7, Intel(R) Core(TM)i5 CPU, RAM:4GB made by Panasonic).
I have a huge problem in executing a dump file on vagrant.
I wouold like to execute the dump file into passion_navi database by commanding "mysql -upassion_user -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump".
However, after inputting the password "123Passion!?", the follwoing error occurs.

**ERROR:**

> ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless
>   option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive
>   mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''.

I tried many things to clear this error;

**1)** Since I first thought the cause was that the password includes "!?", I logged in mysql, made a new user and execute the command again, but failed. 
Checking the user information on mysql, I tried other combinations of the commans as follwos, but failed.

----------------the commands I tried start-----

```
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -upassion_user -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump
Enter password:
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'passion_user'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

```
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -upassion_user -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump
Enter password:
```

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'passion_user'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

----------------the commands I tried end-----

**2)** I also checked the host of vagrant, and it was "dev.passion-navi.com.local".
I cannot understand is that the error code says

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

even thoug the hostname is "`dev.passion-navi.com.local`"; the "root" changes according to the name that I set in the command of `"mysql -u -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump".`
I am guessing the command would succeed if I change something and make the error code says like'`root'@'passion_navi`', but I have not clue to find the way...

FYI, the "**database.php**" file is defined as 
[image]

Comment: so did you try `mysql -u root@dev.passion-navi.com.local -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I did, but failed...
-----------------------
[root@dev db]# mysql -u root@dev.passion-navi.com.local -p passion_navi < ./test_data.dump

Enter password:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@dev.passion-navi.com.local'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: sorry for bad looking. Line break does not seem to work..

Comment: I also tried them, but everyline was denied (ERROR 1045 (28000))____
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -upassion_user -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -upassion_user -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -u'passion_user'@'dev.passion-navi.com.local' -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____
[vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -upassion_user -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump<br/>

Comment: [vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -uroot dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____
                [vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -uroot -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____
                [vagrant@dev db]$ mysql -uroot -p dev.passion-navi.com.local < ./test_data.dump____